# Calculate previous results in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to complete an interesting research, and add new features to existing dataset

```
ID      DATE           LEAGUE         HOME        AWAY    H_GOALS A_GOALS PREV_H_GOALS PREV_A_GOALS
9911 "2005-01-01" "Bundesliga 1" "Wolfsburg"  "Schalke 04"    2      1          NULL      NULL
9822 "2005-01-01" "Jupiler League" "Beveren" "Lokeren"        2      1          NULL      NULL
9823 "2005-01-01" "Jupiler League" "Waregem" "Westerlo"       2      3          NULL      NULL
9824 "2005-01-10" "Jupiler League" "Westerlo" "Beveren"       4      1           3         2
9932 "2005-01-10" "Bundesliga 1" "Bayern Munich" "Wolfsburg"  2      0          NULL       2
9933 "2005-01-10" "Bundesliga 1" "Ein Frankfurt" "Schalke 04" 0      1          NULL       1
```

Now, I want to add additional columns like

- `MATCH_GOALS` - goals kicked in previous match that team
- `PREV_RESULT` - result of previous game [1 - win, 2- draw, 3 - lose]
- `ALL_GOALS_IN_SEASON` - total goals kicked by the team in this season

My attempt for case #1 is not correct:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_time DESC) AS rowno,
       LEAD(m.match_score) OVER (ORDER BY start_time DESC) as MATCH_GOALS, -- #1

FROM match as m
WHERE (m.home = m.home OR m.away = m.away) #fail
ORDER BY start_time DESC
```

Can you advise appropriate window functions (PostgreSQL), or fixed example?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Each row corresponds to two teams.  Which is the team that you want to consider?

Comment: I am looking for getting previous info for both team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution tested in `SQL Server`, but I see that `PostgreSQL` has support for all the goodies in SQL Server (CTEs, Window functions etc.), so this should be a good start.

Your data structure is quite unfriendly for direct window function appliance, so a `CTE` obtains it in a way easier to deal with:

```
ID, Date, League, Team, Goals
```

This allows to get previous information, since team is present in a single column.

Also, first `CTE` computes if the team's result in that particular Match.

Second `CTE` actually gets information about previous match, using [LAG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) window function.

```
;with PivCTE AS (
    SELECT ID, Date, League, Home AS Team, HGoals AS Goals, 
        (CASE WHEN HGoals > AGoals THEN 1 WHEN HGoals = AGoals THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS Result,
        SUM(HGoals) OVER (PARTITION BY Home ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS AllGoals
    FROM Match 
    UNION
    SELECT ID, Date, League, Away AS Team, AGoals AS Goals,
        (CASE WHEN HGoals < AGoals THEN 1 WHEN HGoals = AGoals THEN 2 ELSE 3 END) AS Result,
        SUM(AGoals) OVER (PARTITION BY Away ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS AllGoals 
    FROM Match
),
PrevData AS (
    SELECT ID, Date, League, Team, 
        LAG(Goals, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY Date) AS PrevGoals,
        LAG(Result, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY Date) AS PrevResult,
        AllGoals
    FROM PivCTE
)
select M.*, 
    PH.PrevGoals AS HomePrevGoals, PA.PrevGoals AS AwayPrevGoals, 
    PH.PrevResult AS HomePrevWin, PA.PrevResult AS AwayPrevWin,
    PH.AllGoals AS HomeAllGoals, PA.AllGoals AS AwayAllGoals
FROM Match M
    JOIN PrevData PH ON PH.ID = M.ID AND PH.Team = M.Home
    JOIN PrevData PA ON PA.ID = M.ID AND PA.Team = M.Away
ORDER BY M.Date DESC
```

**Setup data:**

```
create table Match (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Date DATE NOT NULL,
    League NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Home NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Away NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    HGoals INT NOT NULL,
    AGoals INT NOT NULL
)

insert into Match values 

(9911, '2005-01-01', 'Bundesliga 1', 'Wolfsburg',  'Schalke 04',    2,      1),
(9822, '2005-01-01', 'Jupiler League', 'Beveren', 'Lokeren',        2,      1),
(9823, '2005-01-01', 'Jupiler League', 'Waregem', 'Westerlo',       2,      3),
(9824, '2005-01-10', 'Jupiler League', 'Westerlo', 'Beveren',       4,      1),
(9932, '2005-01-10', 'Bundesliga 1', 'Bayern Munich', 'Wolfsburg',  2,      0),
(9933, '2005-01-10', 'Bundesliga 1', 'Ein Frankfurt', 'Schalke 04', 0 ,     1)
```